# width: calc( 100%-250px) is not working full screen

Tags: html, css, layout, width

I have splited the layout into two areas.

left side: `250px`

right side: `100%-250px`

but it appears that the right side is still 100% in chrome. it says its 1440px width.
you can see the image here:
[image].

I wanted to apply flex space between but when i do that the last part goes off the screen since it's 1440px.

please help

Comment: Did you add spaces around ```-``` as so: ```100% - 250px```?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your CSS when looking through dev tools? For example, is your calc laid out correctly (see @prettyinPink comment) plus you don't seem to be allowing for margins or padding. If you show us your actual CSS instead of describing it we could probably find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a grid to do so

```css
.nav {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
}

.logo {
  background-color: red;
}

.bar {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An example with the elements with and without spacing between them.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
}

.left {
  width: 200px;
  background: #2797f3;
}

.right {
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  background: #65b0b3;
}

.left.space {
  width: 250px;
}

.right.space {
  width: auto;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>

</nav>
<br>
<nav>
  
  <div class="left space"></div>
  <div class="right space"></div>

</nav>
```